# Getting error "java.lang.IllegalStateException:The driver executable does not exist"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have imported my selenium code from windows to mac and installed chromedriver for mac and updated systemproperty accordingly.but it is throwing exception and showing previously set path:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/Preet12/Desktop/Selenium/AddaStore/C:\Users\cp\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe

however the path in mac is : /Users/Preet12/Desktop/Selenium/AddaStore/chromedriver 2

it is showing path of window also i.e. C:\Users\cp\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe

Code:

```
public class WithTestNG 
{



WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void StartBrowser()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/Preet12/Desktop/Selenium/AddaStore/chromedriver 2" );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();


    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Navigating to the folder containing chromedriver and run 
"chmod +x chromedriver"